# Delete an entry from db on PHP page exit

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a php page in which a user tries to find online people.

There a search button, clicking on which, an entry is made for the current user in the database and the control goes inside a loop, where every 5 secs a search is made in the database to find if a new entry has been made, if an entry is found then the details of the partner is shown to him.

I want that if the user exits or navigates away from the page before a partner is being found, then his entry must be deleted from the db.

I am trying to store the 'id' created against the user inside a session variable, make an ajax call and delete the entry, but somehow this concept is not working.The data is not getting deleted. Is this because of the loop which is still finding the user or something else, m not able to get it.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong with my approach ?

A code snippet that I am using is hereby

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 funcDeleteonexit();
return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}

function funcDeleteonexit(){
  $.get("functions.php",{
      data:"delete"
  },function(data,status){
 });
 }
```

Inside my functions.php, I have

```
if($_GET){
if ($_GET['data']=="delete"){
    echo deletefromDb();
   }
}


function deletefromDb() {

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $currentid = (int)$_SESSION['currentId'];

    $query1 = "delete from test where id =". $currentid;

    $mysqli->query($query1);
    $mysqli->close();
    return $currentid;
}
```

Comment: Your script is full of bad practices including, `global state`, `code duplication` and breaking all of SOLID principles.

Comment: hey dave I am a php novice. Can you please point out the flaws in my code ?

Comment: I'd recommend `www.phpmaster.com`. Start from novice tutorials

Comment: thanks for recommendation. Do you have a solution to my problem ?

Comment: $currentid = (int)$_SESSION['currentId']; add a ; at the end

Comment: but then how will i get the value of the id for the query ?

Comment: i suggest you to use `ignore_user_abort` in your php code

Answer (score 0):

If you want something done when someone exits the page, this will in most cases give you trouble if you want a specific event to be fired then. There will be cases a browser cannot fire the event (p.e. client crash etc.).

Therefore I'd suggest a different approach. Control this from the server side, and don't rely on the users browser or input.

Firstly, you can poll your data while regularly firing Ajax events from the browser. You've not stated this, but I think you do something like this:

```
function yourrequest(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET", 
       url: "your/php/script.php",
       success: function(data){
          // do something, p.e. update a div 
       }
   });
};

setInterval(yourrequest, 5000);
```

(Please don't tear this code sample apart, its just to show the basics).

On the server side, you already have the users id somewhere in your database. Add a timestamp field to this table (call it last_request or something like that). Everytime you send some data to the client, check if there are users with a last_request below your desired threshold, and delete those ids. No need to wait for a specific event then.

This needn't be done exactly there, you can also do something different, p.e. a cleanup job cronned every 5 minutes or so which does this seperately to not disturb the users request at all.

Comment: but there is an issue in your approach..actually my approach follows FIFO logic i.e. the entry which is entered  must find a partner first. So there might be a case where a person1 has already left and his data is still there in db, so when person2 tries to find a partner, he will find an partner ho is already offline

Comment: You will have this problem anyway to some extent, so better tackle it where you control it best - and thats from the server. Its not an issue in my approach, is a general problem you have to deal with when you want something done like this.

Comment: so you are saying there is no break through to my problem, i ll have to manage with second hand options ?

Comment: You're relying on the user/browser to do something without looking into what happens if they don't behave like you want them to. That has to be dealt with if it is necessary for your application. Track them on your server and delete the events when you feel it is necessary. I've done something similar while coding a complex web platform. I want to know when they exit the site, too - therefore they regularly send events (for other things too, like checking for mails and such), and I use the lack of an event to determine if a user logged off without clicking a button. Works like a charm.

Comment: "I use the lack of an event to determine if a user logged off without clicking a button." - How do you determine this ?

Comment: As I've explained in my reply to your initial question: Let the browser send a cyclic keepalive, use this to update the field I've described. If fields don't get updated, it can be assumed the user left the page.

Answer (score -1):

I'm suggesting that browser just not sending ajax, or interupting it. 
So try to make your AJAX request synchronous. For JQuery seems to be set async parameter to false

```
$.get("functions.php",{
      data:"delete",
      async : false
  },function(data,status){
 });
```